# How to change Encoding.default_external for whole system? OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, character-encoding

I stopped program with pry, then I type

```
[1] pry(Module1::Class1)> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:Windows-1252>
```

In another mac, default value of `Encoding.default_external` is **UTF-8**. I changed locale variables to UTF-8, and encoding in ***irb*** works fine, but not in project stopped. With byebug is the same.

System is **macOSX**, **ruby 2.3.3** through **rbenv**.

Comment: closed due to wrong investigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LANG` env variable to influence the default external encoding:

```
ruby-2.3.4 Desktop$ LANG=en_US.US-ASCII irb
2.3.4 :001 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>

ruby-2.3.4 Desktop$ LANG=de_CH.UTF-8 irb
2.3.4 :001 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

it is also possible to override it with the `-E` options:

```
ruby-2.3.4 Desktop$ LANG=en_US.US-ASCII irb -E utf-8
2.3.4 :001 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: it works with irb, but not with project stopped with pry or byebug

Comment: How did you start this "project"? What is this "project"? Just ruby script, a Rails application? You need to make sure that the project is started with correct settings. Also: if you have CP1252 as default encoding? Where is it running, sounds like Windows?